# Getting 405 error in angularjs post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, cors

I have tried accepted answers in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for this problem.
In angularjs,when i send a `post` request to local `Api` it works.but when i change to cross domain api it does not work.

This is my code

```
 var myapp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','http-auth-interceptor'])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }])
     .factory('featuresData', function ($http) {
        return{          
            doCrossDomainGet: function(data) {
                return $http({
                    url:'http://example.com/api/login',
                     type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({"username":"test_teacher" , "password":"123"}),
        contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);


        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
                })
            }        
        }
});
```

I am getting this message in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load example.com/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

The Api works fine from `Android,Ios` client apps and from CURL

```
curl command
```

`curl -X POST  -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://example.com/api/login -d '{"username":"test_teacher","password":"123"}'`

```
curl output

{"username":"test_teacher","roles":["ROLE_TEACHER"],"access_token":"7q8dcreo5bngk32jq8nmefrfgp6nope2"}
```

Comment: have you tried adding access to allow origins (for requests) at your server end?

Comment: Are you sure, that your "example.com" uri accepts POST -Data?

405 means, "Method not allowed", maybe they only accept GET/PUT?

Did you analyze the response header? It should state, what methods are allowed

Comment: @kfis POST method is allowed on server , but I am not able to get any response from server. I am getting this message in console ` XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.`

Comment: @V31  Is it possible to force angular to make cross-domain requests , even when access to allow-origins is not set in server?

Comment: you can try `dataType: "jsonp",`

Comment: can you describe which server stack you are using? this CORS issue is related to your server, so knowing what you are using is necessary to answering the question properly.

Comment: @Claies we are using grails server .android,ios client apps are able to consume this api.

Comment: According to this answer, you can only solve the issue on the server, not on the angular client side
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin
You have to adjust the server response header

Comment: The API works from your android and other stuff, because they are not bound to the CORS-Restriction, that are built in into the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular app and your backend grails api are not on same domain. So when you make an api call from angular to grails backend, it is actually a cross domain ajax call. You cant make cross domain ajax calls unless you have configured your app accordingly.

See [cors plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/cors) - it will help you support cors.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue ,after a long research i found a simple solution which is working for me.

Remove all the CORS related settings in web.config

like

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Just add these two lines in the WebAPIconfig.cs

```
// Web API routes
```

var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

and your post request from angular

```
 Factory.postData = function (data) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: urlBase+'api/url',
            data: data,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        return request;
    }
```